# Can I have SSH client running DURING computer boot?

Tags: ssh, startup, boot

My computer is too slow to start. 
(especially because I have a window 7 system installed in my computer. And I am working on a virtual machine with Linux, it take about 10 min to start everything on my 4-core intel7)

GOAL: I would like to initiate a SSH session to a distant sever as soon as possible and start working with it (keyboard+screen, no graphic server). And have the full OSs loading in background.

This project exists on [linux](http://dev.kakaopor.hu/early-ssh/):("to have SSH access during the boot" [link](http://random.kakaopor.hu/?s=early%20ssh))
As my host system is Windows, it doesn't apply. Any alternative ?

Comment: I doubt that there is such a product.  You might consider asking, "Why does my nice hardware take forever to boot into Windows 7?"

Comment: I already did, and my answer would be to install linux. But this is a corporate laptop with some preinstalled software and I want to be able to use Outlook (and lync) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you would like to connect to to you Linux VM (distant server). In that cas you can connect as soon as sshd deamon is ready so, "early ssh" makes a lot of sense here despite the fact your host is windows VM.

Comment: Right, easy-ssh would allow to log in while the virtual machine is booting. Really impossible to do it during windows boot?

Comment: Windows works differently and services are loaded after system startup so, even if you would install any sshd service it will be started after system is operable. What you could try is to prioritize sshd service to be started as the first service after TCP/IP thus, you might be able to login a bit earlier.